# When I click on Item_1 I want to close other opened items.How tp do that in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have next situation:
when I click on Item_1 it opens(collapse) all it's children, when I click on it again - it closes.
I want to close it's children when I click on other item.
I use angulajs. all collapse children code is in html:
Parent html:

```
<div  ng-repeat="folder in vm.folders track by $index">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="end end"  flex="10" ng-click="showChildren[$index]=!showChildren[$index];vm.setCurrent(folder.id);">
            <div>
                <md-icon class=" menu-toggle-icon"  style="color: #C2D3F0;font-size:20px;" md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right" ng-if="folder.children.length>0"  ng-class="{ open: showChildren[$index] }" onmouseover="this.style.color='#ffffff'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#C2D3F0'"></md-icon>
            </div>
    </div>
    <ul  ng-show="showChildren[$index]">
        <li ng-repeat="child in folder.children track by $index"  ng-include="'app/components/work/leftsidenav-work/work-iteration-child.tmpl.html' ">
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

children html:

```
 <div layout="row" layout-align="end end"  flex="10" ng-click="showGrandChildren[child.id]=!showGrandChildren[child.id];vm.setCurrent(child.id);">
    <div >
        <md-icon class=" menu-toggle-icon"  style="color: #C2D3F0;font-size:20px;" md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right" ng-if="child .children.length>0"  ng-class="{ open: showGrandChildren[child.id] }" onmouseover="this.style.color='#ffffff'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#C2D3F0'"></md-icon>
    </div>
</div>
<ul  ng-show="showGrandChildren[child.id]" class="padding-left-20" >
    <li  ng-repeat="child in child.children" ng-init="openChildInput=false;" ng-include="'app/components/work/leftsidenav-work/work-iteration-child.tmpl.html' " >
   </li>
```

Comment: For these you need to provide us more info like - are you using any frameworks like bootstrap to get your collapse to work. Also javascript if you have used them. A  Fiddle would be great. This is too generic, we can't tell you where you're going wrong unless we have something to work on.

Comment: I use just angular and angular material... and here to collapse (to show/hide)  I use just 'ngShow' directive.

Comment: Try this angular accordion 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/